# mongodb servers can restart but the status error

Tags: mongodb, macos

macos bigsur 11.4

mongodb-community@4.2

Homebrew 3.2.0-59-g196ec61

```sh
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community@4.2` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@4.2` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2)

```sh
brew services list
```

mongodb-community@4.2 error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist

```sh
sudo cat  /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

```
2021-06-26T11:18:57.026+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2021-06-26T11:18:57.039+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2021-06-26T11:18:57.039+0800 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:18:57.039+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2021-06-26T11:18:57.039+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
```

then i

```sh
rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

now the log is

```
2021-06-26T11:40:26.976+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2021-06-26T11:40:26.984+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-06-26T11:40:26.985+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /usr/local/var/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-06-26T11:40:26.986+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2021-06-26T11:40:26.986+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2021-06-26T11:40:27.541+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624678827:541176][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624678827:541176][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.541+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624678827:541497][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624678827:541497][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.541+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624678827:541729][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624678827:541729][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.541+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624678827:541949][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624678827:541949][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.542+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624678827:542167][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624678827:542167][13476:0x10c276e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.542+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2021-06-26T11:40:27.542+0800 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:40:27.542+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 925
2021-06-26T11:40:27.542+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
2021-06-26T11:50:32.312+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2021-06-26T11:50:32.314+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-06-26T11:50:32.370+0800 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13996 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=tangfeideMBP
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.12
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5593fd8e33b60c75802edab304e23998fa0ce8a5
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-06-26T11:50:32.371+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2021-06-26T11:50:32.374+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-06-26T11:50:32.374+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /usr/local/var/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-06-26T11:50:32.374+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2021-06-26T11:50:32.374+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2021-06-26T11:50:33.138+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624679433:138458][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624679433:138458][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.139+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624679433:139627][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624679433:139627][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624679433:139999][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624679433:139999][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624679433:140299][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624679433:140299][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1624679433:140557][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1624679433:140557][13996:0x110586e00], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 665: /usr/local/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission denied
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 925
2021-06-26T11:50:33.140+0800 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
```

i tried uninstall & install mongodb-community@4.2
but no work

i want use brew install mongodb-community  not  download tgz

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

my log is

```
2021-06-26T16:56:11.129+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2021-06-26T16:56:11.131+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-06-26T16:56:11.141+0800 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16280 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=tangfeideMBP
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.12
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5593fd8e33b60c75802edab304e23998fa0ce8a5
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-06-26T16:56:11.142+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-06-26T16:56:11.143+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2021-06-26T16:56:11.143+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-06-26T16:56:11.144+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /usr/local/var/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-06-26T16:56:11.144+0800 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2021-06-26T16:56:11.144+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2021-06-26T16:56:11.737+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697771:737816][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 307 through 308
2021-06-26T16:56:11.803+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697771:803716][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 308 through 308
2021-06-26T16:56:11.867+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697771:867812][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 307/896 to 308/256
2021-06-26T16:56:11.950+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697771:950264][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 307 through 308
2021-06-26T16:56:12.006+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:6322][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 308 through 308
2021-06-26T16:56:12.050+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:50624][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2021-06-26T16:56:12.120+0800 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2021-06-26T16:56:12.124+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables. Logging enabled? 1
2021-06-26T16:56:12.128+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2021-06-26T16:56:12.128+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.128+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.128+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down journal flusher thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.292+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.293+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down checkpoint thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.293+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
2021-06-26T16:56:12.293+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
2021-06-26T16:56:12.383+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:383569][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 308 through 309
2021-06-26T16:56:12.425+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:425294][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 309 through 309
2021-06-26T16:56:12.489+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:489618][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 308/2176 to 309/256
2021-06-26T16:56:12.581+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:581244][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 308 through 309
2021-06-26T16:56:12.639+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:639630][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Recovering log 309 through 309
2021-06-26T16:56:12.689+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1624697772:689602][16280:0x10e837e00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: MustDowngrade: Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog. Collection: a.p, terminating
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the global connection pool
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutting down free monitoring
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Shutting down full-time data capture
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down the HealthLog
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  -        [initandlisten] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-06-26T16:56:12.855+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

and i tried install mongodb-community@4.4

my log is

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.625+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.626+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.632+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.633+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.633+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":18288,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"tangfeideMBP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.633+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.633+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.5.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.633+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.635+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.635+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.636+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:12.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:13.151+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:13.151+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"45: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:13.151+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":947}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-26T20:36:13.151+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade.

i dont know how to fix

```
mongod --dbpath '/Users/tangfei/data/db'
```

its works
i think macos cant created /data/db

/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

log
Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade.

now i tried edit my config

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /Users/tangfei/data/mongo/log/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /Users/tangfei/data/mongo/data
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

brew services stop mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community

this looks successful
sudo lsof -i :27017

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mongod  12019 tangfei    9u  IPv4 0xb34606b03f96cf9      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
```

but

brew services list

```
Name              Status  User    Plist
mongodb-community error   tangfei /Users/tangfei/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

so why  brew services Status is error

log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.459+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.464+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.464+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.465+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12994,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/tangfei/data/mongo/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"tangfeideMBP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.465+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.465+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.5.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.465+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/tangfei/data/mongo/data"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/Users/tangfei/data/mongo/log/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.469+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/Users/tangfei/data/mongo/data","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:54.469+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.272+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:272209][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.315+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:315511][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.394+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:394068][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 4/11008 to 5/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.487+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:487577][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.551+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:551282][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.596+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:596349][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.596+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:596440][12994:0x10e308e00], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.608+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1624758535:608220][12994:0x10e308e00], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.652+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1183}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.652+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.661+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.665+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.674+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.680+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.681+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/Users/tangfei/data/mongo/data/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.683+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.684+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-27T09:48:55.684+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Comment: Reason: 13: Permission denied

Comment: Looks like the mongod user has not write permissions on `/usr/local/var/mongodb`

Comment: Your initial install refers to a configuration file at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.  Please add the config file contents to your post.  Also if you run as yourself with mongod --dbpath - this is fine but you probably want to refer to the config file using the -f option.  Things like network binding, log file location, authorization, etc. are in the config file.

Comment: I am running into the same issue, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following three steps:

1. Manually recreate the `/usr/local/var/mongodb` directory.
2. Remove the `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file.
3. Run `mongod` command.

Ensure the creater of the above two files same as the user who run the `mongod` command.